# Get a collection of detected objects from PredictionClient

Tags: google-cloud-automl

Am using google cloud automl java sdk. I have created my own trained model. Is there any way that I can get access to the collection of detected objects in an image so that I can draw bounding boxes around them. Right now I get only the detected labels.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. Its a known feature request, so stayed tuned